# Collection of lines from a file

Tags: clojure

This should be an easy question, but I've spent several hours and I still don't understand how to properly use sets in Clojure. I'm attempting to read a file and store each line in a set.
This is my code so far.

```
(def dictionary #{})
  ;(conj dictionary "hi")
  (defn readDictionary []
    (doseq [line (clojure.string/split-lines 
       (slurp "C:\\Working\\Other\\dictionary.txt"))]
      (println line)
      (conj dictionary line)))
  (readDictionary)

  (println dictionary)
```

I can append the "hi" string to the set and each line gets printed out within the doseq, but the set ends up blank when I print it out.

I've very familiar with OO programming, but functional programming is something new for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not with sets as such. The problem is that `conj`, like most of the core library, does *not* have side effects. So the expression:

```
(conj dictionary line)
```

... *evaluates* to `dictionary` with `line` added to it, leaving `dictionary` (and `line`) quite unchanged. So the `doseq` produces a sequence of sets, each containing one line.

The call

```
(readDictionary)
```

... evaluates this sequence of single-member sets, then discards it, since it is not bound to anything. Hence the call has *no net effect*.

I think you want something like this (untested):

```
(defn readDictionary [file-name]
  (into #{} (clojure.string/split-lines (slurp file-name))))

(def dictionary (readDictionary "C:\\Working\\Other\\dictionary.txt"))

(doseq [line dictionary] (println line))
```

In Clojure, you have to get used to working with pure (side-effect free) functions operating upon immutable/persistent data structures.

Comment: Thanks! That was a really helpful explanation. Any good starting tutorials for Functional programming? I've had a hard time knowing what to search.

Comment: I started with [*The Little Schemer*](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/BTLS/) - a catechism of the basics of recursion and lists in the Scheme dialect. As for Clojure: [Try Clojure](http://tryclj.com/) lets you play with a REPL in the browser; [4Clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/) offers a staircase of problems to climb from elementary to hard (still some to do ... grrrrrr). The official docs have a [Getting Started](http://clojure.org/getting_started) page which refer to these and others. Enjoy!

Comment: @qzcx ... and when you've worked your way through these, you'll appreciate why [KobbyPemson's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25085714/1562315) is better than ours.

Answer (score 1):

Read lines from file into set

```
(with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "C:\\Working\\Other\\dictionary.txt")]
   (set (line-seq rdr)))
```